# Looking for a way to keep two decimal places without rounding up

Tags: java, decimal

I have to display my outputs with two decimal places and the program outputs should be 205.16 for monthly payment and 12309.91 for total payment. Before using decimal format to round the answers where correct but after rounding to two decimal places the outputs are now .01 to high. What can I do to remove the extra decimal places without rounding up .01?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;


/**
 *DriverMortgageClass
 */

public class DriverMortgageClass
{
    public double annualInterestRate;
    public int    numberOfYears;
    public double loanAmount;
    public double monthlyPayment;
    public double totalPayment;
    public double monthlyInterestRate;

    DecimalFormat fmt = new    DecimalFormat ("0.00");

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DriverMortgageClass().start();
    }

    //declare private mortgage object
    private Mortgage mortgage;

    public DriverMortgageClass()

    {   
        mortgage = new Mortgage();
    }
    public void start()
    {

        //get input for interest rate
        String annualInterestRateString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter yearly interest rate, for example 8.5",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        annualInterestRate=Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRateString);
        mortgage.setAnnualInterestRate(annualInterestRate);


        //get input for number of years
        String numberOfYearsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number of years as an integer, for example 5",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        numberOfYears= Integer.parseInt(numberOfYearsString);
        mortgage.setNumberOfYears(numberOfYears);


        //set loan amount
        String loanAmountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter loan amount, for example 10000.00",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        loanAmount= Double.parseDouble(loanAmountString);
        mortgage.setLoanAmount(loanAmount);


        //Invoke monthly and total payment
        monthlyInterestRate=annualInterestRate/1200;
        monthlyPayment=loanAmount*monthlyInterestRate /(1-(Math.pow(1/(1+monthlyInterestRate),numberOfYears*12)));
        totalPayment=monthlyPayment*numberOfYears*12;

        //display monthly and total payment
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The monthly payment is"+ " " + fmt.format(monthlyPayment)+'\n'
                +"The total payment is"+ " " + fmt.format(totalPayment));  

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you can multiply a `double` by 100, cast it to an `int` then back to a `double` and divide by 100.

Comment: convert to cents, do your math in cents, convert back to dollars at output time

Comment: @infixed Not a good idea. Read the answer below to find out why. int [32 bits], double[64 bits] among other things.

Comment: were you under the impression that a double couldn't be used in units of cents as well as dollars?  `dollars = int(cents)/100.0`

Comment: sorry, wrong language   `dollars = floor(cents)/100.0.  Unless you deal with negatives

Answer (score 4):

Use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormatt df = new DecimalFormat( "#.00" );
df.format(1.478569); // 1.48
```

Don't want the rounding up?

```
double c = 1.478569d;
c = (double)((long)(c*100))/100;    // 1.47
```

The double casting way might overflow [[Jonny Henly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1241334/jonny-henly) noted below]. Beware. :)

There are numerous ways of doing this. Alternatively,

```
df = new DecimalFormat( "#.000" );
String num = df.format(1.478569);
num = num.substring(0, num.length()-1);    // 1.47
```

Does it help?

Comment: I like the second way, although if the number is too big it could overflow.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Spot on, sir! :)

Comment: Might be better to cast to a long, since `double` and `long` are usually both 64 bit.

Comment: Yep. I casted to a `long`. Can still go wrong, and then `BigDecimal` comes in!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RoundingMode.FLOOR like that

for Kotlin

```
number.toBigDecimal().setScale(2,RoundingMode.FLOOR).toDouble()
```

for JAVA

```
            new BigDecimal("1.555").setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```